# Why my node calls didBeginContact method when its not in the Scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.overPow || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.overPow{
            let sk = delegateForCollision!.view as! SKView
            let newScene = GG(fileNamed: "GG")
            newScene!.delegateFor = delegateForCollision
            newScene?.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            sk.presentScene(newScene)
        }
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.glem && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.kappa{
            contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()

            glem++
            glemLabel.text = "SKAŁY: \(glem)"

        }

        if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.glem && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.kappa{
            contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()

            glem++
            glemLabel.text = "SKAŁY: \(glem)"
        }


    }
```

`glem` and `kappa` `categoryBitMask` nodes are colliding so `glem` variable should be ++ one time then node is removed from scene but it looks like this method is called more times during next frames. I see it in logs because I added `print("\(glem)")` in glem didSet. Why does it happen?

Comment: 1st  you are not handling contacts correctly.  bodyA and bodyB will never guarantee certain categories,  so you need to handle this in code.  2nd, post how you create your sprites, and how you remove your sprites

Comment: Actually categories are detected allways just how they should even if I did something wrong. I am 100% sure that proper code is called. I checked it adding logs and the glem node disappears after contact. Only problem is that this code is called 3-6 Times with single contact even though a node disappears after first call.

Comment: if you look at your code,  you are doing the same thing twice for your one circumstance, (glem++)  This is bad because you can end up not duplicating your code correctly, causing unwanted issues.  Instead you should do something like `let firstBody = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask ? contact.bodyA : contact.bodyB` & `let secondBody = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask >= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask ? contact.bodyA : contact.bodyB`  This will guarentee that your catgegory masks are aligned from lowest to highest,  then in your code you only need 1 branch statement

Comment: As far as duplicate node calls go,  again, you are not presenting where you are creating the nodes,  I am going to assume remove only happens in the statement removeFromParent.  BTW, removeFromParent does not immediately delete the object code,  the node will still exist until the update  cycle has completed,  then the update cycle will remove all of it's temporary holdings of the node, and if there are no other place that the node is being held,  then the node will delete

Answer (score 0):

I changed `glem++` to `if contact.bodyB.node?.parent != nil{glem++}`
 and now it works as it should.